# Divisor Logic not working

Tags: boolean, modulus

Here is what I have:

```
public static boolean isDivisor(int num, int Divisor) {
    int remainder = num%Divisor;
    if (remainder >= 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, what's happening is it's reading in two values, getting the remainder and checking if it's a divisor. The problem I am having is that it always returns as true even if the numbers are not divisible (i.e. for 5, 2 is not a divisor). I am confused as to why this isn't working. Thoughts?

Comment: Code works... just tested isDivisor(5,2) (returns false) and isDivisor(10,5) (returns true)

Comment: I took a copy of your method passed in 5 and 2 and got back false as expected (using C#)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. But this is better (C# version but for java is almost the same):

```
public static bool isDivisor(int num, int Divisor) {
    return num % Divisor == 0;
}
```

Also, variable names should start with lowercase character: (check comment 1/2)

```
public static bool isDivisor(int num, int divisor) {
    return num % divisor == 0;
}
```

Moreover since this is C# code method name should be written with capital letter:

```
public static bool IsDivisor(int num, int divisor) {
    return num % divisor == 0;
}
```

The last example is just for completeness, you can ignore it since you're writing in Jave and therefore camelCase is perfect.

Comment: If we're going to be providing style suggestions as answers, shouldn't we use a lowercase "d" in `Divisor`?

Comment: You're right (+1) but I was only showing the usefulness of the if/then/else :)

Comment: just tested it again, still not working with the 5,2 case (returns true but should be false), I tested it on my laptop which has NetBeans 7.3.1 and my computer with Netbeans 7.0.1... I can tell the code is correct, but I can't seem to get it to work..